# SSH into Unix from Windows using existing ssh keys in Unix

Tags: windows, ssh, unix, ssh-keys

I currently have a setup as below:

```
 Unix OS1        ---->         Unix Server 1
           (SSH using keys)
```

The command I use to login from **Unix OS 1** is ssh **user@hostname** In this case no password is asked as ssh keys are already setup.

Now, I want to ssh into **Unix Server 1** from my **Windows PC** using a client like Putty. But when I try to login, it keeps asking for password which I don't have.

So is it possible to extract the ssh keys from my existing unix setup and set it up in Putty so that I am login to the UNIX server?

Comment: First you need to consider janos's answer. However, in case for some reason you cannot make server side change, you can get the the ssh key from your current client OS under $HOME/.ssh folder. The file name is id_rsa. I use cygwin in Windows and never used Putty so I am not sure how should you import this file into Putty but you should be able to google it.

Comment: Thanks @Codism. I googled up and generated a putty compatible file using Putty Gen. But the key is being refused. In the authorized_key file in the server, I am seeing a From tag and some hosts mentioned there. So, can this be responsible for the key being refused?

Comment: It appears like you put a wrong file into authorized_keys file. You should append your new public key file to authorized_keys. This is what my id_rsa.pub file look like(generated by ssh-keygen): ssh-rsa base64-encoded-key My-Name <email>

Comment: Also, don't forget putty needs to access the private key when the connection is being established.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's strongly discouraged to copy private keys from one machine to another.
The recommended way is to create a new set of keys on each machine from which you want to connect to the server, and authorize the public keys on the server one by one.

You can generate keys on the Windows machine for PuTTY using the `puttygen.exe` utility. Save the public and private keys in separate files. If I remember correctly, the public key format generated by PuTTY is not 100% the same as what you need to put in the `authorized_keys` file on the server. Make the necessary adjustments. It should be a single line, looking something like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDKsi7Zlj8JU0QzL+Uw3nONnyYRkXFCkirmB//ZGVtgKSsxcBURSjjIbw5zBro5g9VRSnto6onxXSTlguhQi2OyWwDypl8QcXJ/QTf9W94A62pdTHtopO3mdBHD7WgdAndb5R78ZADLU7lLMGm1ObifpI4Uk6pKvCKMe43cL8DMP5O+ym2FE3lqHdMj+/cqE0nLyqHZdlMC8VKORsw6F8a0TA4/yl6+LGNxUcWCOW8b1BDUozyggZpqCcUU6Kq/JAiOBWc7MOqe7b1NeKHuBS/2k0S0AfZngp5z7OrNYO4UODcKLF9YN3elWa+9VlDUrED9BmxG8eh8zZnDY+rv8KlT youruser@yourmachine
```

You can use the `pageant.exe` utility to store your passphrase in memory so that you don't need to re-enter it every time you connect to the remote server with `putty`, `pscp`, `psftp`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the steps, but in this scenario I do not have permission to edit the authorized_keys file. So, I will not be able to add any new public key to the file.

Comment: Requesting to authorize a new public key is the correct solution. Copying the private key from one machine to another undermines security.